# Could not resolve hostname nodename nor servname provided, or not known only with rsync

Tags: ssh, rsync, continuous-integration, bastion

I work with sensitive data, so my host requires that I use a bastion to access the server. 
I can connect to the server without any problem in SSH using the following command: `ssh userremotemachine@remotemachine:userbastion@bastion`

On the other hand, as soon as I issue the following command: `rsync -az source/ userremotemachine@remotemachine:userbastion@bastion:/destinationpath`, I get this error message:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname remotemachine: nodename nor
>   servname
>   provided, or not known rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes
>   received so far) [sender] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data
>   stream (code 12) at
>   /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-52.200.1/rsync/io.c(453)
>   [sender=2.6.9]

Can you tell me what this could be about?

Thank you in advance